# What are the smallest dimensions/resolution I can use for a 7ft x 2ft banner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resolution, ppi, cs4

I am designing a banner which will be printed at 7ft x 4ft.

I am using Photoshop CS4.  The images are not vectors.  The original poster artwork has been done at 300 ppi for A4 printing.  I was hoping to re-size the canvas of the poster (after saving as a new file) to keep the 300 ppi resolution but working on a smaller scale to reduce the file size.  This is mainly to avoid having to copy all the layers in to a new file to recreate the existing image.

I have looked around at various questions already on the site, but can't seem to find an answer.  The common recommendation seems to be that banners or other large-scale pieces that will be viewed from a distance only need to be around 75-100 ppi, but I was hoping to work with a higher resolution and smaller size, instead of lower resolution and larger canvas.

Any and all advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A5 @ 300 ppi = 25MB, A6 @ 600ppi = 25MB. 1/2 the size, double the resolution, same file size same CPU processing etc etc

Comment: I meant to add: A4 is about 12" on one side, so the unaltered unresampled artwork is going to be approx 40ppi @ 7 ft. To get 100ppi, you'd need ((7x12)x100)) by ((4x12)x100)) pixels. Also the A5 in first comment is a typo, should be A4

Comment: Speak to whoever will be printing/reproducing the banner. They'll have specifications to follow. Anything else is guesswork - sometimes good guesswork, but still guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies!  I will get the contact details for the printers.  At least if I don't manage to get in contact with them, I'll be able to work it out.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: This should have been added as an answer, @horatio! I suggest you elaborate a bit more and add it as one.

Comment: I agree with Scott, talk to the printer first because the design may change the printing method if you are trying to print image quality VS production quality.  We charge differently because we are using more ink and time.  Again, as Scott stated before asking us ask the printer on what they require or prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Decision on dpi varies according to banner positioning in space, content and printing technology. Often 100dpi is enough - but don`t take it for constant.

7x4ft in 100dpi resolution means 8400x4800px image.

For estimating image size, there are handy dpi calculators like this http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/printing/1_calculators.htm#Print

Comment: a quick rule of thumb for *file size* is divide the each pixel dimension by 1000 (actually 1024, but keep it simple) (shift the decimal 3 places to the left), multiply them, then multiply by the number of colors (RGB=3, CMYK=4). The result is the approximate file size in MB. ( 8400x4800 > 8.4x4.8x3 > 120 ). Add a color for each Alpha channel. This does not take into account layers.